# Windows Media Player Plugin Development in Windows 10 (Visual Studio 2019)

Tags: plugins, windows-10, visual-studio-2019, wizard, wmp

I'm looking to create a very simple UI plugin for Windows Media Player, similar to this: https://obsproject.com/forum/resources/windows-media-player-title-artist-text-output-ticker.402/, but with the ability to choose the path and name of the text file.

I haven't been able to find any answers to WMP Plugin development questions on here since 2013, and the last actual answer give was for Visual Studio 2008. I'm now using Visual Studio 2019, so almost all of the tutorials, guides, and FAQs are massively out of date.

I've been following the setup guide here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//aa969437(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

After a few hours, I've finally been able to install the Windows 7.1 SDK by deleting all my C++ 2010 redistributables, and temporarily rolling back my .NET Framework 4 version to RTM. I now have `wmpwiz.ico`, `wmpwiz.vsdir`, and `wmpwiz.vsz`.

The interal version of VS2019 is 16.0, so I've edited my `wmpwiz.vsz` file to read:

```
VSWIZARD 7.0
Wizard=VsWizard.16.0

Param="WIZARD_NAME = Windows Media Player Plug-in Wizard"
Param="ABSOLUTE_PATH = C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Samples\multimedia\WMP\Wizards\wmpwiz"
Param="FALLBACK_LCID = 1033"
```

and I've placed the three files into `%UserProfile%\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Templates\ProjectTemplates\Visual C++ Project\`, but nothing shows up in the Start New Project window.

Obviously, I'm using technology that hasn't been touched for over a decade, so I don't know if this approach will even work anymore. Are there any modern guides on how to do this, or would it be quicker and easier to try to dig out my old VS2005 install disks, and hope they're not too scratched?

If this SDK Sample has been depreciated with age, are there any other wizards available that can be used for WMP plugin development? Preferably using C#, as I'm a .NET programmer, but I'm happy to trawl through C++ if I absolutely have to.

Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: The wizard is not only composed of these 3 files, it's composed of the templates files that comes with it. You can extract them and build your project by hand. It's not perfect though, some placeholder texts will have to be replaced, etc. In case you don't have all, here is link https://1drv.ms/u/s!AsmmEDGvydk2nzXhlEYHJSNp48y8?e=m092g4